# How do I change the default icon created by KML Reader on a Here API map? Or substitute an image?

Tags: here-api

I'm using a KML file to load placemarks on a map, so I do not edit the individual markers. Therefore, I'd like to change the default color and size of the icon, which defaults to a really large blue bubble. I've tried editing the ICON entries in the CSS file but have had no success.

Here's how I'm loading the markers using **H.data.kml.Reader**

```
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
var map = new H.Map(...);
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
var reader = new H.data.kml.Reader('/temp/pure-gas.kml');
reader.parse();
layer = reader.getLayer();
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Comment: Here's what I'm dealing with, any suggestions welcome! http://pure-gas.dev.ims.net/extensions/here-map.html

Comment: Note: KML support is the ONLY reason I'm using Here. So the markers must be loaded automatically from a KML file. Which works great, I just can't seem to change those markers' attributes in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default Icon's bitmap can't be changed. You should create one custom Icon and use it for all markers.
In order to change KML parsed objects, instead of adding layer to the map you can get array of all parsed objects using `getParsedObjects()` method, update and then add them to the map:

```js
var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28px" height="36px">' +
    '<path d="M 13 0 C 9.5 0 6.3 1.3 3.8 3.8 C 1.4 7.8 0 9.4 0 12.8 C 0 16.3 1.4 19.5 3.8 21.9 L 13 31 L 22.2' +
    ' 21.9 C 24.6 19.5 25.9 16.3 25.9 12.8 C 25.9 9.4 24.6 6.1 22.1 3.8 C 19.7 1.3 16.5 0 13 0 Z" fill="#AAF"/>' +
    '<path d="M 13 2.2 C 6 2.2 2.3 7.2 2.1 12.8 C 2.1 16.1 3.1 18.4 5.2 20.5 L 13 28.2 L 20.8 20.5 C' +
    ' 22.9 18.4 23.8 16.2 23.8 12.8 C 23.6 7.07 20 2.2 13 2.2 Z" fill="#B32"/>' +
    '</svg>',
  customIcon = new H.map.Icon(svg, {
    size: {w: 13, h: 18}
  }),
  group = new H.map.Group(),
  reader = new H.data.kml.Reader('YOUR_KML_FILE');

reader.addEventListener('statechange', function (evt) {
  if (evt.state == H.data.AbstractReader.State.ERROR) {
    console.log('Error in KML reader', evt);
  }
  else if (evt.state == H.data.AbstractReader.State.READY) {
    reader.getParsedObjects().forEach(function(obj) {
      // assume all parsed objects are Point Geometries
      obj.setIcon(customIcon);
    });
    group.addObjects(reader.getParsedObjects());
    map.addObject(group);
  }
});

reader.parse();
```

See [KML reader description](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.data.kml.Reader.html) and [Icon description](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.map.Icon.html) for more details

Comment: I think you didn't understand my dilemma: I'm not adding markers manually. I'm using the KML support to add many thousands of markers automagically.

Comment: Sorry, but your question didn't describe the way how you load KML file neither how you create map objects out of it, therefore I answered with the sample code for creating Marker with custom icon. 
Do you use H.data.kml.Reader class to load the file?

Comment: var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
    var map = new H.Map(...);
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
    var reader = new H.data.kml.Reader('/temp/pure-gas.kml');
         reader.parse();
    layer = reader.getLayer();
    map.addLayer(layer);

Comment: So I updated my answer with sample code for KML reader.
Please update also your question to include KML reader.